# SSE thread.sleep blocks other threads

Tags: asp.net, razor, server-sent-events, thread-sleep

The following simplified code (C#) is the server side of an SSE. When I use `Thread.Sleep()` instead of `Response.Write("retry:10000\n\n")` other ajax request keep hanging. How do I create a proper SSE event-stream?

```
Response.ContentType = "text/event-stream";
DateTime echo;

while (true)
{
    var db = Database.Open("SSE");
    echo = db.QueryValue("select last_change from table");
    db.Close();
    Response.Write(string.Format("data:{1}\n\n", echo.GetHashCode()));

    ///// debug this works 
    Response.Write("retry:10000\n\n");
    Response.Flush();
    Response.Close();
    return;
    /////////// this doesn't work

    Response.Flush();
    if (Response.IsClientConnected == false)
    {
        break;
    }
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);

}
```

P.S. I am also planning on using a `SqlDependency`, but haven't figured this out yet.

EDIT:
I'm thinking the problems lies with the sessionstate.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have "return;" after 
Response.Close();

Didn't you forget to delete this?

Comment: it is placed in a while loop and a bit of overkill never killed anybody

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the problem lies with the sessionstate, ASP.net only allows one active session thread. If you set the sessionstate to off or read-only it should be fixed. This is not availble in razor syntax as far as i'm aware, thus I created an .ashx with `IReadOnlySessionState`.

```
 public class SSE : IHttpHandler, IReadOnlySessionState
    {

public class SSE : IHttpHandler, IReadOnlySessionState
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {

        context.Response.ContentType = "text/event-stream";
        DateTime echo;
        while (true)
        {
            var db = Database.Open("SSE");
            echo = db.QueryValue("select last_change from table");
            db.Close();
            context.Response.Write(string.Format("data:{0}\n\n", echo.GetHashCode()));
            context.Response.Flush();
            if (context.Response.IsClientConnected == false)
            {
                break;
            }
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);

        }

    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```